# Wordpress Users REST API returning rest_cannot_edit_roles for Administrator role

Tags: wordpress-rest-api

I have created an API Key and Secret in the WooCommerce settings of a WordPress site, linked to a user with Administrator role.  I'm able to use this API key successfully for various API calls to the site.

However, when I try to execute this API call to update a user role:
`POST /wp-json/wp/v2/users/35`

```
{
    "roles": ["technician"]
}
```

I get back a 401 Response with the following content:

```
{
    "code": "rest_cannot_edit_roles",
    "message": "Sorry, you are not allowed to edit roles of this user.",
    "data": {
        "status": 401
    }
}
```

Yet, as mentioned already, the user associated with the API key used in the API call is an Administrator, with full permissions.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by authenticating the API call with an Application Password configured on the user profile, instead of the WooCommerce API key and secret.